# How to boost a document if full query text is present in it? - Solr

Tags: solr

I need to give priority to the documents where full search term occurs. For example if the search term is "Georgia Tech", I want the document having "Georgia Tech" in it to have extra boost than those having more frequent "Georgia" term in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is almost standard:

1. index it two fields (use copyField), one whitespace (or similar) tokenized, one as a keyword.
2. you use edismax and boost the keyword field with more weight than the other